# Trying to access rowid of phpgrid in another page but not getting it in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to retrieve rowid of a phpgrid on the same page I included it using SESSION e.g

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
```

However when it use `var_dump($id);` I get the response `String(8)` without the actual value.  Below is my code.

1. lasttest.php

   ```
        <?php
         require_once('../phpGrid_Lite2/conf.php');       
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

          <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Select Multiple Rows</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            </script>
          </head>

          <body>

            <?php

          $dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM uploaded", "id", "treated"); 



         $onSelectRow1 = <<<ONSELECTROW
          function(status, rowid)
          {
          //alert('event 1');
          console.log(rowid);
          console.log(status);

        /* example to redirect a new URL when select a row */
        cabinet = $('#uploaded').jqGrid('getCell',rowid,'cabinet');
        cabinet_name = $('#uploaded').jqGrid('getCell',rowid,'cabinet_name');
        //alert(rowid);
         //window.location = encodeURI("http://example.com/" + "?" + "cabinet=" +cabinet + 
         "&cabinet_name="+cabinet_name);
         }
         ONSELECTROW;
         $dg->add_event("jqGridSelectRow", $onSelectRow1);
         $dg -> display();
          ?>
          </body>

        </html>
   ```
2. retrieverowid.php

```
    <?php
            require_once('checklogin.php');
            $date=@date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
            require_once('connect1.php');
            $do = new db;
            $do->doconnect();
            //Get Return Page
            $username=$_SESSION['username'];
            //$cate=$_SESSION['cate'];  
            $mytype = $_SESSION['mytype'];
            $Link =$_SESSION['link']; 
            $count = count($Link);
            $loggedUBranch= $_SESSION['cate'];
    
            $uploaddir = "uploadsbenefit/"; 
    
            $command = "";

            if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                $myfilename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $FileToAddSize =$_FILES['file']['size'];
                
                $ispdf = @end(explode(".",$myfilename));
                //$file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $ispdf = strtolower($ispdf);
                
                 if($ispdf !='pdf'){
                     echo "Sorry, You can only merge PDF files, press browser back button to continue";
                     exit;
                 }
                 
                 //Get original filename from the database
                $id = $_SESSION['id'];
                var_dump($id);
                
                $Orig = $do->gett("select * from uploaded where id ='$id'");
                $OriginalFileNameOnServer = "uploadsbenefit/".$Orig['file_name'];
    ?>
</table>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="73%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

  <div align="center"><span id=""></span>

    <div id='retrievetable' class="style17">
      <?php include 'lasttest2.php'?>

    </div>

    <table style="width: 700px; height: 14px;" align="center" width="706">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="myresult" align="left">
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>


            <div class="uploader">

              <form id="actionform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p> <input name="file" id="file[]" type="file" /></p>
                <p>Allowed Files: .pdf </p>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Merge Files" />
                <input type="button" name="Delete" id="deletebtn" value="Delete Selected" />
              </form>

            </div>
```

I want a sitiuation whereby when I click on the Merge files Button I should be able to retrieve the clicked rowid using Sesssion, which I will thereafter use to select the actual selected row from the database.

I have tried several options but it is not working for me. Anytime I try using `var_dump($id)` i get `string(8)` without the actual rowid number.

Comment: I've tidied this up a bit for you, but for future reference you do really need to read [ask] and [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) before posting anything else, and/or before you [edit] this post any further. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, session values aren't readable unless you put `session_start();` at the beginning of your PHP script, and I don't see that anywhere here...perhaps you've omitted some of it?

Comment: Also I see lots of places where you read _from_ the Session, but I don't see anywhere that you put any data _into_ it?

Comment: Okay. Thank you. There is session start in one the include files. Here it is   $id = $_SESSION['id'];
                var_dump($id);

Comment: ok. And where/when did you put a value _into_ that Session field? Again, I only see code where you try to read _from_ it. From what you're saying it seems like somehow the value contains 8 spaces maybe, and/or other invisible characters. Without knowing how the value got into the field, there's no way to start debugging or diagnosing the cause of that.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson I did not pass the value into the session field. I don't know where i can do that . Just confused.

Comment: You can do it at the time you know what value you want to put into it. How is the application deciding which ID should be in the session? You talk about retrieving a row ID but it's not entirely clear what you mean. P.S. If it reports string(8) then you must have put _something_ into it!

Comment: It is a phpgrid, I want to retrieve the rowid after clicking on the grid row using javascript as stated above. If i use alert(rowid) i always get the rowid. Now i want to get rowid using session on the same page after clicking the submit button.

Comment: Why would you need the Session for that? Just send the selected rowID to PHP when you click the submit button. JavaScript could put the ID into a hidden field in your form for you. (I'm assuming you have a form somewhere, which the submit button is part of? That wasn't really clear).

Comment: How can i do that? any sample code?

Comment: To put something into a form field using jQuery you can use the normal `.val()` function. If you prefer to use vanilla JS then set its `.value` property. If that's not the issue, then where else are you stuck with how to do what you need? You haven't even confirmed yet whether you actually have a form which this submit button you mentioned is part of